# Why does Snakemake redirect output to a non-existing folder?

Tags: bash, pipeline, snakemake, output-redirect

I have a rule in Snakemake which `shell` section translates to something like that:

```bash
echo "Hello" > output_folder/output_file; cat input_file >> output_folder/output_file
```

Note that `output_folder` is a child folder for the one where Snakemake runs.

That worked well, but I've decided to use another folder for output, and that folder is not a child of the current one. I have to provide an absolute path. Now my pipeline fails:

```bash
/usr/bin/bash: line 1 /absolute/path/output_file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/bash: line 1 /absolute/path/output_file: No such file or directory
...
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

Indeed, after running the pipeline with the `--printshellcmds` flag and repeating the same sequence of commands in bash it produces the same error.

So now I'm confused: why does it work for the child directory? I've repeated the sequence of commands for the child directory and bash produces the error (which is expected), while Snakemake successfully redirects output to the file in a non-existing folder.

**Update:** removing the `cat ... >>` part doesn't help and the behavior is the same. I've tried to replace absolute path with the relative one. Now I'm getting another error:

```
WorkflowError:
Error recording metadata for finished job ([Error 2] No such file or directory: '<current dir>\\.snakemake\\metadata\\Li4vLi4vLi4vZmxhc2hiYWNrYm9uZV93YXRjaC9kb2N0cmluZXMvQ2Fycm9sbC9iYWNrYXBwX3JlZmFjdG9yL1NwYW5pc2gvaW5zZXJ0X2ludG9fcGFyYWRpZ20udmVyYi50eXBlLmhpZXJhcmNoeV9zZWxlY3RfcGFyYWRpZ20udmVyYi50eXBlLmhpZXJhcmNoeXRtcC5zcWw='). Please ensure write permissions for the directory <current dir>\.snakemake')
```

```
I'm running it on Windows under MSYS2 environment.
```

Comment: What are the rule's inputs and outputs - is `/absolute/path/output_file` specified as an output? The immediate gotcha I can think of is that Snakemake only will create missing directories if it knows it needs them.

Comment: The `shell` section looks like: `echo "Hello" > {output}; cat {input} >> {output}`. If Snakemake creates the directory prior to running this command, then why doesn't that work for absolute path?..

Comment: It *should* do so for absolute paths as well. So there's something else involved. Off the top of my head, two questions: does it still fail in the same way if you only have the `echo` without the `cat` or have `echo "Hello" > {output} && cat {input} >> {output}` ? And how much of the absolute path exists? (Also, could you post the rule in question with inputs, outputs and anything else involved?)

Comment: Removing `cat` doesn't help. Please see the update in the question.

Comment: Why are there backslashes in that "Error recording metadata..." message? Is this on a Windows system?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes, Windows + MSYS2.

Comment: If you are on Windows, `/absolute` is not a valid absolute path. Try `c:/absolute/` (also depending on how exactly the Windows drives are exposed in your environment; IIRC Cygwin calls it `/c/` etc).

Comment: @tripleee to be more precise it is `/c/absolute/path/output_file`, as I'm using MSYS2.

Comment: Can you provide a Snakefile to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @dariober, after some experiments I discovered that the issue may be related to the absolute filename. The hash for the temporary file Snakemake creates while running (*Li4vLi4vLi4vZmxhc2hiYWNrY...NoeXRtcC5zcWw*) is 167 symbols, the path to the folder with Snakefile is 71 symbols (including *C:\*), Snakemake requires additional 23 symbols for *\.snakemake\incomplete\* part of the path. Somehow if the target is a child folder, that is not an issue, and Snakemake creates a filename that exceeds limits in case of non-child folder.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a hack that does not solve the issue, but perhaps it will help: setup a symlink to the absolute path of interest, so that the symlink is in the child folder. Not ideal, but should work.